# Learning Unit testing using NUNIT for a sample micro service and getting an error

Tags: .net, testing, nunit

I just started learning unit testing using Nunit with my WebApi project.

I've developed one test case for my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace HelloService.Controllers
{
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("hello");
    }
}
}
```

This test

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using HelloService.Controllers;
using NUnit.Framework.Legacy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace HelloService.Tests
{
public class HelloControllerTests
{
   [Test]
public async Task Should_Return_Hello()
{
// Arrange
var controller = new HelloController();

// Act
var actionResult = controller.Get() as 
OkObjectResult;

// Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
Assert.AreEqual("hello", actionResult.Value);
}
}
}
```

I am getting these errors "Assert does not contain a definition for IsNotNull" and "Assert does not contain a definition for AreEqual"
Can any one please help me with this.
Edited : I changed the Assert to Classical assert but When I do dotnet run I encounter
error CS0579: Duplicate
'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute
This error. I have add
false this line in my .csproj file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't say what version of NUnit you are using,(*) I'm guessing that it is version 4. `Assert.AreEqual` and `Assert.NotNull` are what NUnit calls "Classic Asserts". They are the very first form of NUnit assertions and were the only form until 2007, when the "Constraint-based Assert Model" was introduced. If you are using some documentation, which **only** mentions the classic model, then those docs are very old indeed.

If, for some reason, you want to use the legacy "Classic" assertions, you should replace "Assert" with "ClassicAssert" in your code each time you use one. Alternatively, you could install an older version of NUnit, prior to version 4, but that seems silly if you are just learning NUnit. My advice would be to start learning the newer model in the first place.

In that case, you would be writing

```
Assert.That(actionResult, Is.Not.Null);
Assert.That(actionResult.Value, Is.EqualTo("hello"));
```

You can let Intellisense or a more up to date version of the documentation guide you to other assertions.

Comment: Hello Charlie, Thanks for responding. When I do dotnet run I encounter error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute
this error. I have add  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> this line in my .csproj file, Could you please help me with that.

Comment: @Abaiz It's not useful to add new questions in your comments or for me to answer them in a comment. Comments may eventually be deleted but questions and answers remain for other people to see. If you add this as a new question, however, you will have to provide some further info, e.g. a copy or snippet of your project file. Also, if I answered your question, please accept the answer.